# The use of omega as the worst-case running time instead of O

Tags: algorithm

We use omega() for the best-case running time and O() as the worst-case running time. But in the text below from CLRS, they use omega() for worst-case running time (the underlined part). Can omega() be used as a worst-cast running time instead of O()?

[CLRS, Chapter 3, Page 49](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haY1j.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- "The algorithm runs in O(f(n))" means that there exists a constant k such that the algorithm runs in at most k f(n).
- "The algorithm runs in Omega(f(n))" means that there exists a constant k such that the algorithm runs in at least k f(n).
- When you're saying "even in the worst case, the algorithm runs in O(f(n))", you are complimenting your algorithm: you are saying the algorithm is guaranteed not to be slower than k f(n).
- When you're saying "the worst case runs in Omega(f(n))" you are criticizing your algorithm: you are saying that for every n there is an input of size n on which the algorithm will be slower than k f(n).

In most situations, people are interested in the O() statement and don't bother too much with the Omega() statement.

### An example: runtime of quicksort

- Quicksort runs in O(n^2)
- For every n, there exists a particular array of size n on which quicksort runs in Omega(n^2)
- However, it is wrong to say that the running time of quicksort is Omega(n^2), since in some cases (in most cases, in fact), quicksort runs in much less than n^2
- If the array is shuffled uniformly at random, then the expected running time of quicksort is O(n log n)
- We usually say something along the lines of "The runtime of quicksort is O(n^2), and its average running time is O(n log n)."

Comment: Many thanks Stef!  So is it wrong to say that the running time of quicksort is Omega(n^2)?

Comment: Yes it is wrong to say that the running time of quicksort is Omega(n^2). The worst-case running time of quicksort is Omega(n^2). But the best-case running time of quicksort is O(n log n) (and also Omega(n log n)).

Comment: We usually say something along the lines of "The runtime of quicksort is O(n^2), and its average running time is O(n log n)." "Average running time" here is very ambiguous but means "the expected running time if the array was shuffled uniformly at random". Writing a rigorous proof of the average runtime is harder than it sounds, though.

Comment: Sorry Stef can I ask the reason why it is wrong, please?

Comment: Because in some cases (in most cases, in fact), quicksort runs in much less than n^2. So you cannot say "quicksort runs in Omega(n^2)".